# Checking for null object type parameter in Azure YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm setting up a build template and can't figure out the syntax for an optional object type parameter. In my pipeline I'm calling the template like this:

```
stages:
- template: aspnet-core.yml@templates
  parameters:
    database:
      name: 'SomeDatabase'
      server: 'SomeServer'
```

I have the parameter defined like this in the template:

```
parameters:
  database: null
```

I want to do a check like this in the template so I can run a task conditionally:

```
- ${{ if ne('${{ parameters.database }}', null) }}:
```

However, it's not liking the keyword null in the if statement, and I don't know how to represent the fact that it wasn't passed in. What are my options here?

Comment: Did you try an empty string instead of `null`?

Comment: Yeah but what happened was I got an error when running the pipeline: Unable to convert from Object to String. Value: Object

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use below expression to check if a parameter is empty. For below example

```
- ${{if parameters.database}}:
```

Below is my testing template and azure-pipeline.yml.

the script task will only get executed when `database` is evaluated to true. I tested and found `database: ""` and `database:` will be evalutated to false. If it is defined as `database: {}`, it will be evaluated to true.

Template: deploy-jobs.yaml

```
parameters:
  database: {}

stages:
- stage: buildstage
  pool: Hosted VS2017

  jobs:
  - job: secure_buildjob
    steps:
    - ${{if parameters.database}}:
      - script: echo "will run if database is not empty"
        displayName: 'Base: Pre-build'
```

azure-pipeline.yml:

```
stages:
- template: deploy-jobs.yaml
  parameters:
    database: ""
```

To execute some tasks if database is empty you can use below statement:

```
 steps:
    - ${{if not(parameters.database)}}:
      - script: echo "will run if database is empty"
        displayName: 'Base: Pre-build'
```

Comment: That does work syntactically, but it also requires that the caller pass in a parameter with a value of "". I'm starting to get the impression that YAML doesn't have a way to know that a parameter wasn't passed using this syntax. I did find though that I am able to skip a task using conditions. I had to check the database.name property though, which doesn't raise a null reference exception if not passed weirdly.

condition: and(succeeded(), ne('${{ parameters.database.name }}', ''))

Comment: Since checking the database.name property in the condition is working, you can post this solution as an answer.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like an alternative to the if syntax is to use [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) instead. This allows you to skip over the step. I had to check a property of the object though to see if it was actually passed, so not super ideal.

```
condition: and(succeeded(), ne('${{ parameters.database.name }}', ''))
```

Comment: It looks like parameter expansion is not working right in template expressions. There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/64) on this which is still open at the time I'm writing this. There is a proposal on that issue to use condition as a workaround, similar to what you present in your answer.

Comment: One thing to note - could be pro/con - using - ${{if parameters.database}}: syntax over condition syntax is that with "if" - if the condition doesn't evaluate to true, the step(s) are not even rendered. This might only apply to compile time parameters and not runtime... In some cases the "if" syntax can lead to cleaner looking build output by removing sections not run. Using conditions, you would still see it "skipped".

Answer (score 8):

I've found another solution to that, you can work with the length of the incoming object.
If the object is empty, it's length is 0

```
parameters:
  - name: myObject
    type: object
    default: []
  
steps:
  - ${{ if not(eq(length(parameters.myObject), 0)) }}:
      - script: |
          echo "hello world"
        displayName: "next task"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the default as:

```js
parameters:
  database:
    name: ''
    server: ''

then check:
- ${{ if ne(parameters.database.name, '') }}:
  <run-your-task>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter can be an empty object, empty array, null or empty string. An object parameter cannot be null, only empty object or string is allowed. For example : {} or [] or ''

In Azure DevOps, parameter don't accept empty string alternate is to pass null. Below are some example on how to handle null and empty string.

Example #1 : Object parameter type

```
parameters:
 - name: database
   type: object
   default: {}

jobs:
- job: secure_buildjob
  steps:
  - ${{ if and(ne(length(parameters.database), 0), ne(parameters.database, '')) }}:
    - script: echo "will run if database is not empty"
      displayName: 'Test task'
```

Example #2 String parameter type with default null

```
parameters:
 - name: database
   type: string
   default: null

jobs:
- job: secure_buildjob
  steps:
  - ${{ if and(ne(parameters.database, ''), ne(parameters.database, 'null')) }}:
    - script: echo "will run if database is not empty"
      displayName: 'Test task'
```

Example #2 String parameter type with default empty string

```
parameters:
 - name: database
   type: string
   default: ''

jobs:
- job: secure_buildjob
  steps:
  - ${{ if and(ne(parameters.database, ''), ne(parameters.database, 'null')) }}:
    - script: echo "will run if database is not empty"
      displayName: 'Test task'
```